# Angular 5, condition in html break bootstrap column

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

In my angular 5 project I have to display some column based on some conditions,
I have just updated bootstrap to v4 and now I have some issue with a conditional template.

There are columns with "ng-star-inserted" class displayed in a wrong position, maybe there are some error in the code?
This is an example:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="selected.status !== null>
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-10" *ngIf="+totalPayed < +selected.price">
            <button *ngIf="loggedUserService.checkSession()">
                <span class="btn-label">
                    <i class="material-icons">add</i> pay
                </span>
           </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the button misaligned:

[image]

And this is the source code of the rendered page:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`ng-star-inserted` will be added into code if animations are used.

Alternatively, you can use ng-container tag.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loggedUserService.checkSession()">
   <button>
      <span class="btn-label">
           <i class="material-icons">add</i> pay
      </span>
   </button>
</ng-container>
```

`ng-container` is used to apply conditions like *ngIf, *ngFor without impacting html dom.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selected.status !== null">
   <div class="row">
      your code here
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem, do I need 1 ng container for every conditions?

Comment: Wherever `ng-star-inserted` is impacting your output, you could use ng-container. Can help out if you share your implementation of ng-container.